# how to connect my raspberry pi to pc which has no hdmi port but a 5 usb port

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, usb, hdmi, pi-3b+

I am not to find out how to connect rasberry pi to my pc which has no HDMI port 
Any suggestions please . Thanks

Comment: Have you tried https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/remote-access/vnc/README.md

Comment: Note that usually HDMI connectors on PC and laptops are outputs, so is the HDMI connector on the Pi ([see here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/54044/19949). You cannot connect those and expect anything useful to happen. Maybe you can try to explain what you want to do to get better answers. Connect the Pi to a monitor or connect the Pi to a network (and use ssh or vnc as joan suggested).

Comment: i Have a Lenovo c200 all in one destop pc , as i was not able to connect my pi to it (via HDMI) , so i asked for a alternative to connect my pi